# Override the ProcessDialogKey Method on multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a C# Winforms application and use the ESC key to close a form.

I have this piece of code on every form, but I would like to have that in one place:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

This does work, but it means having to add this piece to every form I make.

How can I make this work for every form I have without adding this code to all the forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What prevents you from inheritance?

Comment: @RezaAghaei nothing actually. I just found out that works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest solution (least code write) is to create own form, inheritted from the basic one, and override the method there. Then, everytime You'll create a new form, your `EscapeForm` will be used.

Like this:

```
public partial class EscapeForm : Form
{      
    //You will put there your method
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

And now everyform You'll be using, You can just use this one:

```
public partial class LoginForm : EscapeForm
{
     //All the staff you need to have there..
}
```

Comment: Hehe same idea :)

Comment: @Cid Indeed. =)

Comment: Thanks (both), I will try this asap!

Comment: @Montfrooij Please consider to "accept" this answer if it helped you. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Tatranskymedved, I have done that the moment it worked (of course)

Comment: @Montfrooij Actually, You've just voted, not accepted as final answer. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Learning all the time!

Answer (score 2):

Your forms inherits from `Form` class. You can build a decorator class that inherits from `Form` and then use your forms inherits from that decorator.

In example :

```
public class Decorator : Form
{
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

And then, your form :

```
public class MyForm : Decorator
{
    // your form code
}
```

Comment: Thanks (both), I will try this!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change your forms at all, trap the escape key using IMessageFilter:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyFilter());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Show();
    }

}

public class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
{

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case (int)Keys.Escape:                           
                        Form.ActiveForm.Close();
                        break;
                }
                break;

        }

        return false; // returning false allows messages to be processed normally
    }

}
```